# K8 container causes a CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: bash, docker, kubernetes

I am trying to figure out why the following container goes into a CrashLoopBackOff state. Basically, this container is run as a pod on AKS. It gives CrashLoopBackOff the first time, and then when I apply again, it runs fine.

Could it be an intermittent error?

Any idea or opinion would be greatly appreciated.

The following are the files

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial

ADD setup.sh /src/

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget

ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "-c"]

CMD ["/src/setup.sh"]
```

**setup.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh -e

if [ -z "$SOME_PARAMETERS" ]; then
    wget -P ./cfg/ $SOME_PATH
else
    mkdir -p ./cfg
    echo "$SOME_PARAMETERS" > /cfg/indo
fi
```

Comment: `setup.sh` should behave like a server, so put `sleep inf` at the end of it.

Comment: It'd be better to actually run a server process – a container or Kubernetes pod that's just sleep(1)ing isn't especially useful.  What do you want this container to actually do?

Comment: or make it a job, if you dont need a long running process.

Answer (score 0):

try the following command:

sudo kubectl create deployment POD-NAME --image=IMAGE-NAME -- "sh" "-c" "while true; do sleep 1234; done"